# 2 Tables on one page - buttons on Rows to run different script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with 2 tables and each row has a 'Select' button which needs to run a script when clicked. I've got this working with the first table but can't work out how to get it working with both tables.

Here's the HTML for the tables:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2>Select Main</h2>

<div>

  <br />
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <th scope="col">Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Select</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr class="" id="SK5543333">
        <td>BJ2345</td>
        <td>Laptop 13 inch display</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" id="SK3241235213">
        <td>AZ77656</td>
        <td>Laptop 15 inch display</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>


<h2>Select Accessories</h2>

<div>

  <br />
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <th scope="col">Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Select</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr class="" id="SK3412541">
        <td>MM42412341</td>
        <td>Mouse</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" id="SK95390485">
        <td>KB42341243</td>
        <td>Keyboard</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" id="SK42353">
        <td>USB421341234</td>
        <td>USB Adapter</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" id="SK543647585">
        <td>PWR363456534</td>
        <td>POWER ADAPTER</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

I need to run a different script when users select from the top/Main table and another script when users select from the bottom/Accessories table. Here's my script that runs when the Select button from the first table is clicked:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.btn-success:not([type="submit"])').click(function() {
    // Remove the classes from all of the TR elements
    $(this).parents('table').find('tr').removeClass('success warning danger');
    var productID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    console.log(productID);
    $this = $(this);
    // add the success class to the row and remove the danger class if it was present
    $this.closest('tr').addClass("success");
    $this.closest('tr').removeClass("danger");
    // update the hidden input with the selected productID
    $('#productID').val(productID);
  });
});
```

Not sure how to have another version of this that only runs when the Select button from the 2nd table is clicked?

Comment: Load a different script??? Why not just use different script tags, if you have JavaScript on 2 pages? Just execute the code needed.

Comment: When getting cells/tables/rows using jQuery, use .closest() because then you only target the table you're in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was interrupted writing the answer but you could try something like this:

```
const selectHelper =
  ($me,classToAdd,inputSelector) => {
    $me.parents("table")
      .eq(0)
      .find("tr")
      .removeClass("success warning danger");
    const id = 
      $me.parents("tr")
        .eq(0)
        .addClass(classToAdd)
        .attr("id")
    ;
    $(inputSelector).val(id);
  }
;
const clickActions = {
  one:(e,$me)=>
    selectHelper(
      $me
      ,"warning"
      ,"#inputidOne"
    )
  ,two:(e,$me)=>
    selectHelper(
      $me
      ,"success"
      ,"#inputidTwo"
    )
};
$(document.body)
  .on(
    "click"
    ,`[data-action-click]`
    ,e=>{
      const action = e.target.getAttribute("data-action-click");
      if(typeof clickActions[action] === "function"){
        clickActions[action](e,$(e.target))
      }
      debugger;
    }
  )
```

The button needs a `data-action-click` attribute that has the name of the function you want to execute when clicked:

```
  <button 
    type="button"
    data-action-click="two"
    class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
  >
    Select
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table:first").find('button[type!="submit"]').click(function() {
    $("table:first").find("tr").removeClass("success warning danger");
    $(this).parents("tr").addClass("success");
    $("#productID").val($(this).parents("tr").attr("id"));
  });
  $("table").eq(1).find('button[type!="submit"]').click(function() {
    $("table").eq(1).find("tr").removeClass("success warning danger");
    //Do whatever color you want
    $(this).parents("tr").addClass("warning");
    //Wasn't provided this snippet so I just made up accessoryID
    $("#accessoryID").val($(this).parents("tr").attr("id"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2>Select Main</h2>
<div>
  <br />
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th class="text-center">Select</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="SK5543333">
        <td>BJ2345</td>
        <td>Laptop 13 inch display</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="SK3241235213">
        <td>AZ77656</td>
        <td>Laptop 15 inch display</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<h2>Select Accessories</h2>
<div>
  <br />
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th class="text-center">Select</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="SK3412541">
        <td>MM42412341</td>
        <td>Mouse</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="SK95390485">
        <td>KB42341243</td>
        <td>Keyboard</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="SK42353">
        <td>USB421341234</td>
        <td>USB Adapter</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="SK543647585">
        <td>PWR363456534</td>
        <td>POWER ADAPTER</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[.eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) This returns a jQuery object from a list of jQuery objects by index, whereas indexing with brackets will return HTML content.

P.S. You don't really need `class=""` and `scope="col"` in the table, the HTML I provided doesn't have those. The only real point of the class attribute is to assign multiple CSS attributes easily, unless you're using classes as selectors. Same with scope, I've made many tables and never used scope.

Also, when you do a `thead`, you need to add a `tr` before you add the headers. I fixed that in the code above. (Yes, this does mean that tables support multiple header rows).